# Hides inherited members warning message on my code! - don't know where it come from

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C#, I have a method which is being called when a BUTTON or a keyboard shortcut is pressed. At first, everything goes smooth, and when I'm almost done with my project, I did some code cleaning up (I erased some comments and removed unnecessary codes). But after that a warning message appears and the keyboard shortcut do not function as it was before here's the warning message:

> Warning   1   'Inventory_program.IPForm.Update()' hides inherited member
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Update()'. Use the new keyword if hiding
>   was intended.

Here's my code:

```
    private void Update()
    {
     if (getset.clik2 == 1)
       {
         MessageBox.Show("No data to update, dumbass!!", "!!");
       }
     else
       {
         query = @"select ip_address, pc_name, mac_address, users_owner, locations, remarks
                 from it_ip_inventory ";
         dataGridView1.DataSource = exec.InitConn(query);

       }            
    }
```

I apologize, I don't have the enough popular point to upload an image.

Please help, I don't know how to resolved it. I'm using WinForms.

Comment: You have to change the name of the method `Update()`. The name is taken by the `Control` class. May I suggest `UpdateData()` or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `Update()` is defined for the control base class.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx

In your code you can name things the same as existing (inherited) methods, if they have different arguments (overloading). In your case, your `Update()` has an identical signature as  the built-in method.

I suggest you take the opportunity to re-name the method to something more descriptive, like

```
private void UpdateFromDatabase()
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, it did remove the warning message, though the keyboard shortcut still won't work normally.

but anyway, thanks a lot! Guess I have to post another topic bout my problem.

Comment: For the keyboard short cut, try to trace the event handler called. Look for a method that is declared with `Handles Me.KeyDown`.

Comment: That worked for me too. I was using a method name same as one of the inherited ones. The IDE was giving me strange suggesting to add a 'new' keyword in the controller method. I just renamed the method to something specific and the warning went away. Thanks a lot.